# Type Mismatch with Array: VBA Excel

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I have a 2D array that I want to assign strings to in a certain column. I am getting the error `Type Mismatch` on the line where I assign the string to the specific spot in the array. Any ideas why?

```
Dim WinDesc() as Variant

*other code 

    ReDim Preserve WinDesc(1 To constant, 1 To 2)
    WinDesc(z, 1) = WS_Sel.Cells(1, z).Value 
    WinDesc(z, 2) = "R_counter & " / " & counter" & " products with and " _
    & C_counter & "/" & counter& " other products with" 'Errors here
```

Comment: You can only change the last dimension size with redim perserve.

Comment: You updated your code for array dimension as per Scott's suggestion. Mention that in your question or in a comment. Avoids confusion. What is the data type of your array.? Your string is incorrect.

Comment: Sorry the extra ReDim was a typo. The error is still the same - Type Mismatch.

Comment: And the data type is Variant. I included it in my edit.

Comment: What do you think *this* is doing in your string concatenation: `/`?

Comment: This is a typographical error pertaining to use/misuse of quote marks to identify string literals.

Comment: I would have gotten the error "Syntax error" if I misused quotation marks. I stuck a random one in and this happened, so I do not think it is a syntax error.

Comment: As-is, you're trying to *divide* strings by one another, e.g., `"R_Counter &" / " & " & counter"`... So you're trying to perform mathematical operation on string data, which will raise a mismatch *before* even attempting to assign it to a position in the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a typographical error pertaining to use/misuse of quote marks to identify string literals. This should avoid the mismatch error:

```
WinDesc(z, 2) = R_counter & "/" & counter & " products with and " & _
                C_counter & "/" & counter & " other products with"
```

Updated to reflect that `R_Counter` and `C_Counter` are variables.

Comment: R_counter and C_counter are variables. Should they still have quotation marks around them?

Comment: No, if those are variable names they should not be enclosed.